# Transition loads when screen loads

Tags: css

I'm having a border transition on a focus. When I focus the input field, I want the border to change color. This works.

What I don't want is to let the border load when the page load, which it does now. Why is it doing this?

```
<input type="stad" name="stad" value=""/>

input {
  border: 7px #227a7b solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #1a5a78;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1a5a78 0%, #11c7b8 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #1a5a78), color-stop(100%, #11c7b8));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1a5a78 0%, #11c7b8 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1a5a78 0%, #11c7b8 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1a5a78 0%, #11c7b8 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #1a5a78 0%, #11c7b8 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a5a78', endColorstr='#11c7b8',GradientType=1 );
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  transition: 1s border;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: green 7px solid;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide us the html as well. I want to test this so I can help you.

Comment: I'm confused text has border and you want to change the color of that border on click and you said you don't want to rest the border to the default color on reload the page is that right?

Comment: No, I'm changing the color of the input box. But when opening the page or reloading, the border has a small animation before focussing it.

@Brian It's just an input box. Nothing special.

Comment: please provide some live code here or on jsfiddle because I'm not able to see it, I might see it here.

Comment: I've added the "html". It's just an input field as I said. All the code is there. There's nothing more I can add.